# How to skip csv files that are not in folder

Tags: r, csv, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of CSV files on an amazon S3 bucket which I currently have linked to my Rstudio. I have a loop that paste the name and date of the file so that it can be retrieved from my bucket using `s3read_using()`. However, not all the date ranges are in my bucket and I get an error when the file called cant be found.

Is there a way to just bypass the file and continue searching and loading the ones that exist? I tried using `supressWarnings()` and I can't really find good instructions on using `tryCatch()`.

Comment: Can you please show the code you tried?

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly but I actually found an answer by a user called Makaroni under a question unrelated to mine titled "Read one by one file from s3 in r" . I was able to read all the file names from the S3 as strings and created a loop that only allowed only the files within the range I wanted that were in the string to be read by s3read_using(). The data I am using is pretty sensitive so I could not post it.